# Reduce JavaScript Objects into Array of Formatted Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, formatting, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects in the format

```
{type: number, sub_type: number}
```

I need to sort them into an array of objects formatted like this

```
{
  type_id: (type from at least one object in array above),
  sub_types: [
    (all sub types from objects in array above that match this type)
  ]
}
```

This is what I came up but I think there is a more efficient way.  `rawTypes` is an array of objects in need of formatting, `types` ends up being the array of formatted objects.

```
const typeIds = [...new Set(rawTypes.map(val => val.type))];
const types = typeIds.map(val => ({type_id: val, sub_types: [] }));
rawTypes.forEach(obj => {
  let typeIndex = types.reduce((accum, val, i) => val.type_id === obj.type ? i : accum, 0);
  types[typeIndex].sub_types.push(obj.sub_type);
});
```

I think a better solution would use recursion but I can't think of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

## Look at this approach

```js
var data = [{type: 5, sub_type: 10}, {type: 5, sub_type: 11}, {type: 6, sub_type: 12}];

var obj = data.reduce((a, c) => {
   var current = a[`type_id_${c.type}`];
   if (current) {
     current.sub_types.push(c.sub_type);
   } else {
     var key = `type_id_${c.type}`;
     a = { ...a, ...{ [key]: {sub_types: [c.sub_type], 'key': c.type} } };
   }
   
   return a; 
}, {});

var array = Object.keys(obj).map((k) => ({ 'type': obj[k].key, 'subtypes': obj[k].sub_types }));

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply! I actually didn't know about Array.find()

Comment: @KurtPetrek yes, I think we can avoid that `find` because it's O(n^2), so, look at the updated answer with an O(n) solution.